# How to resolve harmless "java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: xxx/hadoop-client-api-3.3.4.jar" error in Spark when run `sbt run`?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, sbt

I have a simple Spark application in Scala 2.12.

### My App

**find-retired-people-scala/project/build.properties**

```
sbt.version=1.8.2
```

**find-retired-people-scala/src/main/scala/com/hongbomiao/FindRetiredPeople.scala**

```scala
package com.hongbomiao

import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}

object FindRetiredPeople {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val people = Seq(
      (1, "Alice", 25),
      (2, "Bob", 30),
      (3, "Charlie", 80),
      (4, "Dave", 40),
      (5, "Eve", 45)
    )

    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("find-retired-people-scala")
      .config("spark.ui.port", "4040")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._
    val df: DataFrame = people.toDF("id", "name", "age")
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("people")

    val retiredPeople: DataFrame = spark.sql("SELECT name, age FROM people WHERE age >= 67")
    retiredPeople.show()

    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

**find-retired-people-scala/build.sbt**

```
name := "FindRetiredPeople"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.17"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.4.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.4.0",
)
```

**find-retired-people-scala/.jvmopts** (Only add this file for Java 17, for other old versions, remove it)

```bash
--add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
```

### Issue

When I run `sbt run` during local development for testing and debugging purpose, the app succeed running.

However, I still got a harmless error:

```bash
➜ sbt run
[info] welcome to sbt 1.8.2 (Homebrew Java 17.0.7)
# ...
+-------+---+
|   name|age|
+-------+---+
|Charlie| 80|
+-------+---+

23/04/24 13:56:40 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.10.8.125:4040
23/04/24 13:56:40 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
23/04/24 13:56:40 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
23/04/24 13:56:40 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
23/04/24 13:56:40 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
23/04/24 13:56:40 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
23/04/24 13:56:40 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
[success] Total time: 8 s, completed Apr 24, 2023, 1:56:40 PM
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: find-retired-people-scala/target/bg-jobs/sbt_e60ef8a3/target/3d275f27/dbc63e3b/hadoop-client-api-3.3.2.jar
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:3089)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:3036)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadProps(Configuration.java:2914)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:2896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:1246)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Configuration.java:1863)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Configuration.java:1840)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.getShutdownTimeout(ShutdownHookManager.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.shutdownExecutor(ShutdownHookManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.access$300(ShutdownHookManager.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:102)
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: find-retired-people-scala/target/bg-jobs/sbt_e60ef8a3/target/3d275f27/dbc63e3b/hadoop-client-api-3.3.2.jar
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:148)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1851)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1264)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:709)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:243)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:172)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:347)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:72)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:168)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.getOrCreate(JarFileFactory.java:91)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:132)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.parse(Configuration.java:3009)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getStreamReader(Configuration.java:3105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:3063)
    ... 10 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

### My question

My question is how to hide this harmless error?

### My attempt

Based on [this](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/6888#issuecomment-1176377545), I tried to add `hadoop-client` by updating **build.sbt**:

```
name := "FindRetiredPeople"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.17"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.4.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.4.0",
  "org.apache.hadoop" %% "hadoop-client" % "3.3.4",
)
```

However, then my error becomes

```bash
sbt run
[info] welcome to sbt 1.8.2 (Homebrew Java 17.0.6)
[info] loading project definition from hongbomiao.com/hm-spark/applications/find-retired-people-scala/project

  | => find-retired-people-scala-build / Compile / compileIncremental 0s
[info] loading settings for project find-retired-people-scala from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to FindRetiredPeople (in build file:hongbomiao.com/hm-spark/applications/find-retired-people-scala/)

  | => find-retired-people-scala / update 0s
[info] Updating 

  | => find-retired-people-scala / update 0s
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-client_2.12/3.3.4/hadoo…
    0.0% [          ] 0B (0B / s)

  | => find-retired-people-scala / update 0s
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-client_2.12/3.3.4/hadoo…
    0.0% [          ] 0B (0B / s)
[info] Resolved  dependencies

  | => find-retired-people-scala / update 0s
[warn] 

  | => find-retired-people-scala / update 0s
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:

  | => find-retired-people-scala / update 0s
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client_2.12:3.3.4
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /Users/hongbo-miao/.ivy2/localorg.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client_2.12/3.3.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-client_2.12/3.3.4/hadoop-client_2.12-3.3.4.pom
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.unresolvedWarningOrThrow(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:344)
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.$anonfun$update$38(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:313)
[error]     at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:573)
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.update(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:313)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:60)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:59)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:133)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:73)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$20(LibraryManagement.scala:146)
[error]     at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:228)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:146)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:127)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChangedW$1(Tracked.scala:219)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:160)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask0$1(Defaults.scala:3687)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:68)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:282)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:23)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:291)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:282)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:265)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:64)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client_2.12:3.3.4
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /Users/hongbo-miao/.ivy2/localorg.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client_2.12/3.3.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-client_2.12/3.3.4/hadoop-client_2.12-3.3.4.pom
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Apr 19, 2023, 4:52:07 PM
make: *** [sbt-run] Error 1
```

Note in the log, it expects **hadoop-client_2.12-3.3.4.pom**. I think `2.12` means Scala 2.12. However, [hadoop-client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client) does not have Scala 2.12 version.

[image]

To compare, this is how it looks for libraries having Scala version such as [spark-sql](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql):

[image]

Anything I can do to help resolve the issue? Thanks!

---

### UPDATE 1 (4/19/2023):

I updated from `"org.apache.hadoop" %% "hadoop-client" % "3.3.4"` to `"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "3.3.4"` in **build.sbt** based on Dmytro Mitin's answer, so now it looks like

```
name := "FindRetiredPeople"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.17"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.4.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.4.0",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "3.3.4"
)
```

Now the error becomes:

```bash
➜ sbt run
[info] welcome to sbt 1.8.2 (Amazon.com Inc. Java 17.0.6)
[info] loading project definition from find-retired-people-scala/project
[info] loading settings for project find-retired-people-scala from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to FindRetiredPeople (in build file:find-retired-people-scala/)
[info] running com.hongbomiao.FindRetiredPeople
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j2-defaults.properties
23/04/19 19:28:46 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.4.0
23/04/19 19:28:46 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
# ...
+-------+---+
|   name|age|
+-------+---+
|Charlie| 80|
+-------+---+

23/04/19 19:28:48 INFO SparkContext: SparkContext is stopping with exitCode 0.
23/04/19 19:28:48 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.0.0.135:4040
23/04/19 19:28:48 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
23/04/19 19:28:48 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
23/04/19 19:28:48 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
23/04/19 19:28:48 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
23/04/19 19:28:48 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
23/04/19 19:28:48 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
[success] Total time: 7 s, completed Apr 19, 2023, 7:28:48 PM
23/04/19 19:28:49 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
23/04/19 19:28:49 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/22/ntjwd5dx691gvkktkspl0f_00000gq/T/spark-6cd93a01-3109-4ecd-aca2-a21a9921ecf8
23/04/19 19:28:49 ERROR Configuration: error parsing conf core-default.xml
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: find-retired-people-scala/target/bg-jobs/sbt_20affd86/target/f5c922ec/359669fc/hadoop-client-api-3.3.4.jar
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:148)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1851)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1264)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:709)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:243)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:172)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:347)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:72)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:168)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.getOrCreate(JarFileFactory.java:91)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:132)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.parse(Configuration.java:3009)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getStreamReader(Configuration.java:3105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:3063)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:3036)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadProps(Configuration.java:2914)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:2896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:1246)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Configuration.java:1863)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Configuration.java:1840)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.getShutdownTimeout(ShutdownHookManager.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.shutdownExecutor(ShutdownHookManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.access$300(ShutdownHookManager.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:102)
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: find-retired-people-scala/target/bg-jobs/sbt_20affd86/target/f5c922ec/359669fc/hadoop-client-api-3.3.4.jar
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:3089)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:3036)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadProps(Configuration.java:2914)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:2896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:1246)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Configuration.java:1863)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Configuration.java:1840)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.getShutdownTimeout(ShutdownHookManager.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.shutdownExecutor(ShutdownHookManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.access$300(ShutdownHookManager.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:102)
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: find-retired-people-scala/target/bg-jobs/sbt_20affd86/target/f5c922ec/359669fc/hadoop-client-api-3.3.4.jar
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(UnixFileAttributeViews.java:55)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:148)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1851)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1264)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:709)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:243)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:172)
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:347)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:72)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:168)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.getOrCreate(JarFileFactory.java:91)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:132)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.parse(Configuration.java:3009)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getStreamReader(Configuration.java:3105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:3063)
    ... 10 more
```

And my **/target/bg-jobs** folder is actually empty.

---

### UPDATE 2 (4/19/2023):

I tried Java 8 (similar to Java 11), however, still shows same error:

```
➜ sbt run
[info] welcome to sbt 1.8.2 (Amazon.com Inc. Java 1.8.0_372)
[info] loading project definition from find-retired-people-scala/project
[info] loading settings for project find-retired-people-scala from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to FindRetiredPeople (in build file:find-retired-people-scala/)
[info] compiling 1 Scala source to find-retired-people-scala/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[info] running com.hongbomiao.FindRetiredPeople
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j2-defaults.properties
23/04/19 19:26:25 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.4.0
23/04/19 19:26:25 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
# ...
+-------+---+
|   name|age|
+-------+---+
|Charlie| 80|
+-------+---+

23/04/19 19:26:28 INFO SparkContext: SparkContext is stopping with exitCode 0.
23/04/19 19:26:28 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.0.0.135:4040
23/04/19 19:26:28 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
23/04/19 19:26:28 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
23/04/19 19:26:28 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
23/04/19 19:26:28 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
23/04/19 19:26:28 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
23/04/19 19:26:28 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
[success] Total time: 12 s, completed Apr 19, 2023 7:26:28 PM
23/04/19 19:26:29 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
23/04/19 19:26:29 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/22/ntjwd5dx691gvkktkspl0f_00000gq/T/spark-9d00ad16-6f44-495b-b561-4d7bba1f7918
23/04/19 19:26:29 ERROR Configuration: error parsing conf core-default.xml
java.io.FileNotFoundException: find-retired-people-scala/target/bg-jobs/sbt_e72285b9/target/f5c922ec/359669fc/hadoop-client-api-3.3.4.jar (No such file or directory)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:231)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:157)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:171)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:108)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:99)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:152)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.parse(Configuration.java:3009)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getStreamReader(Configuration.java:3105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:3063)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:3036)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadProps(Configuration.java:2914)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:2896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:1246)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Configuration.java:1863)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Configuration.java:1840)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.getShutdownTimeout(ShutdownHookManager.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.shutdownExecutor(ShutdownHookManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.access$300(ShutdownHookManager.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:102)
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: find-retired-people-scala/target/bg-jobs/sbt_e72285b9/target/f5c922ec/359669fc/hadoop-client-api-3.3.4.jar (No such file or directory)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:3089)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:3036)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadProps(Configuration.java:2914)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:2896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:1246)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Configuration.java:1863)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Configuration.java:1840)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.getShutdownTimeout(ShutdownHookManager.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.shutdownExecutor(ShutdownHookManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.access$300(ShutdownHookManager.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:102)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: find-retired-people-scala/target/bg-jobs/sbt_e72285b9/target/f5c922ec/359669fc/hadoop-client-api-3.3.4.jar (No such file or directory)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:231)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:157)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:171)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:108)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:99)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:152)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.parse(Configuration.java:3009)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getStreamReader(Configuration.java:3105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:3063)
    ... 10 more
```

### UPDATE 3 (4/24/2023):

Tried adding `hadoop-common` and `hadoop-client-api`, also no luck with same error:

```
name := "FindRetiredPeople"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.17"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.4.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.4.0",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "3.3.4",  
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client-api" % "3.3.4",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "3.3.4"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add hadoop with `%` rather than `%%` (as written at the [link](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/6888#issuecomment-1176377545) you mentioned)

```
"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "3.3.4"
```

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-client/

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client

It's Java library, not Scala one (like spark-sql etc.)

https://github.com/apache/hadoop

`%%` adds Scala suffixes `_2.13`, `_2.12`, `_2.11` etc. This is irrelevant to Java.

---

Based on `java.base...` in your stack trace, you're using Java 9+. Try to switch to Java 8.

Actually, you seem to use even Java 17

> [info] welcome to sbt 1.8.2 (Homebrew Java 17.0.6)

but

> Supported Java Versions
>
> - Apache Hadoop 3.3 and upper supports Java 8 and Java 11 (runtime only)

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP/Hadoop+Java+Versions

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-17177

---

[How a spark application starts using sbt run.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43759641/how-a-spark-application-starts-using-sbt-run)

[Difference in running a spark application with sbt run or with spark-submit script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53902625/difference-in-running-a-spark-application-with-sbt-run-or-with-spark-submit-scri)

---

You can also try to switch on `fork := true` in `build.sbt`

https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Forking.html#Forking

[Why do we need to add "fork in run := true" when running Spark SBT application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44298847/why-do-we-need-to-add-fork-in-run-true-when-running-spark-sbt-application)

Comment: Thanks Dmytro for the info! I actually initially tried `%`, but also had issue, just didn't notice the error difference. Just added to question.

Comment: @HongboMiao It's important to differ build-time errors (`sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException`), compile-time errors, runtime errors (`java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException`).

Comment: Thanks Dmytro! Just tried both Java 8 and 11, still no luck 

Comment: @HongboMiao What code should I actually run with `sbt run` in order to reproduce? Add reproduction to your question.

Comment: I just added the full code in the question.

Comment: @HongboMiao Thanks for reproduction. But I can't reproduce so far. Empty project with your code, `build.sbt`, `project/build.properties`, Oracle Java 1.8.0_351. Runs without exceptions, prints the dataframe. Did you try to clean your project `sbt clean`? What is this path `hongbomiao.com/hm-spark/applications/ingest-from-s3-to-kafka/target/bg-jobs...` in `FileNotFoundException`? You wrote that your project is in `find-retired-people-scala/...`. I can't see anything connected with Kafka in your `build.sbt` or code. I suspect you're missing some parts necessary for reproduction.

Comment: @HongboMiao  Are you sure you can reproduce in a new project with such build file and such code?

Comment: Oh I can print dataframe too, the app itself works well. However, the error is a little annoying which I hope to get rid of. I tried `sbt clean` but still shows same error. Hmm, the app is [here](https://github.com/Hongbo-Miao/hongbomiao.com/tree/main/hm-spark/applications/find-retired-people-scala) in a mono repo. Other parts are not related at all though. I will try to move to a clean folder and reproduce and report back.

Comment: @HongboMiao So it seems that your project is in `find-retired-people-scala` but `FileNotFoundException` in `ingest-from-s3-to-kafka`

Comment: @HongboMiao Oh, you had `ingest-from-s3-to-kafka` in update 1 but `find-retired-people-scala` in update 2

Comment: @HongboMiao I cloned your repo, cd to `hm-spark/applications/find-retired-people-scala`, commented out `--add-exports`, `sbt run` executes without exceptions

Comment: Nice catch! I cleaned my question with new tries, so far still no luck. I will do a clean try and report back! Really appreciate!

Comment: @HongboMiao Try to add `hadoop-client-api` besides `hadoop-client` to `build.sbt`

Comment: The answer is mostly correct. I don't think any of these additional suggestions are correct, however. It won't solve a JAR not being found on Spark executor. Added new answer

Comment: @Dmytro Mitin Tried a clean clone, commented out `--add-exports`. Tried Java 8 and 11, and still no luck, I will keep digging in! Really appreciate pointing out `%`!

Comment: @HongboMiao Did you try to add `hadoop-client-api` besides `hadoop-client` to `build.sbt`?

Comment: @Dmytro Mitin Yup, I did try adding `"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client-api" % "3.3.4"`, same. I was thinking could it be rated with MacBook Pro M1 chip (?)  Anyway I will try more ways and also check @OneCricketeer's suggestion.

Comment: @HongboMiao Just in case, you can also try to switch on `fork := true` in `build.sbt`

Comment: @DmytroMitin `fork := true` helps, but introduced new harmless errors. I posted at https://stackoverflow.com/a/76095938/2000548 But I guess I will stay with old harmless error in UPDATE 1 for now as I do want to use Java 17. Thanks a lot! 

Answer (score 1):

Regarding first error `sbt run` (after `compile/package`) is not how you [run Spark applications](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit)... `spark-submit` [sets up the client classpath to include Spark](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/bin/spark-class#L24) (and Hadoop) libraries. Sbt should only be used to compile code with the classes you're going to use.

The only reason `sbt run` works locally is because the classpath is pre-configured for you and using any additional environment variables that Spark may need like `SPARK_CONF_DIR` to do additional runtime configuration.

Regarding the remaining errors, `sbt assembly` needs to be used to create an uber jar, with all transitive dependencies (after you add `% provided` to your Spark dependencies and remove hadoop-client since it is a transitive dependency...), as [mentioned in the answer to your previous Spark/sbt question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75799853/2308683)

Here's a plugin that makes this easier for Spark - https://github.com/alonsodomin/sbt-spark

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, thanks! When I submit this application in the Spark cluster, it has no error at all, and I only use `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.3.2" % "provided"` and `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.3.2" % "provided"` now. This question is just more curious about how to get rid of that error when run `sbt run` as it is a little bit annoying. 

Comment: Which error? As mentioned, `sbt run` should not be used for Spark applications

Comment: Thanks for reminding! I am only using `sbt run` during local development for testing and debugging purpose. The harmless error refers to the one when run `sbt run`. The error is also in the title of the question.

Comment: You should still be using `spark-submit` for local development. You may be able to override `sbt run` to execute that instead

Answer (score 1):

(Note this answer resolved the original harmless error I met in the question, but introduced some new harmless errors in my case)

Thanks @Dmytro Mitin!

`fork := true` helps `sbt run` get rid of original harmless error in my UPDATE 1. So the `build.sbt` looks like this

```
name := "FindRetiredPeople"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.17"
fork := true
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.3.2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.3.2",
)
```

Note when I `sbt assembly`, I am still using this (no `fork := true` and add `"provided"`):

```
name := "FindRetiredPeople"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.17"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.3.2" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.3.2" % "provided"
)
```

Note even after adding `fork := true`, it sitll only works in Java 11 and Java 1.8.

So now the log for `sbt run` looks like. It removed the harmless error in the UPDATE 1, but introduced some new harmless errors.

```bash
➜ sbt run
[info] welcome to sbt 1.8.2 (Amazon.com Inc. Java 11.0.17)
[info] loading settings for project find-retired-people-scala-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from find-retired-people-scala/project
[info] loading settings for project find-retired-people-scala from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to FindRetiredPeople (in build file:find-retired-people-scala/)
[info] running (fork) com.hongbomiao.FindRetiredPeople
[error] SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
[error] SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:find-retired-people-scala/target/bg-jobs/sbt_21530e9/target/90e7c350/f67577ef/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
[error] SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:find-retired-people-scala/target/bg-jobs/sbt_21530e9/target/163709c3/4a423a38/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
[error] SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:find-retired-people-scala/target/bg-jobs/sbt_21530e9/target/d9dbc825/8c0ceb42/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
[error] SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
[error] SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
[error] Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j2-defaults.properties
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 WARN Utils: Your hostname, Hongbos-MacBook-Pro-2021.local resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 10.10.8.125 instead (on interface en0)
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.3.2
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO ResourceUtils: No custom resources configured for spark.driver.
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: find-retired-people-scala
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO ResourceProfile: Default ResourceProfile created, executor resources: Map(cores -> name: cores, amount: 1, script: , vendor: , memory -> name: memory, amount: 1024, script: , vendor: , offHeap -> name: offHeap, amount: 0, script: , vendor: ), task resources: Map(cpus -> name: cpus, amount: 1.0)
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO ResourceProfile: Limiting resource is cpu
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO ResourceProfileManager: Added ResourceProfile id: 0
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: hongbo-miao
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: hongbo-miao
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(hongbo-miao); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(hongbo-miao); groups with modify permissions: Set()
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 62133.
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
[error] WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
[error] WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:find-retired-people-scala/target/bg-jobs/sbt_21530e9/target/795ef2be/5f387cad/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.3.2.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
[error] WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
[error] WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
[error] WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMasterHeartbeat
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /private/var/folders/22/ntjwd5dx691gvkktkspl0f_00000gq/T/blockmgr-8cc28404-cae7-4673-85c2-b29fc5dd4823
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 9.4 GiB
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host 10.10.8.125
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO Executor: Starting executor with user classpath (userClassPathFirst = false): ''
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 62134.
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 10.10.8.125:62134
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 10.10.8.125, 62134, None)
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.10.8.125:62134 with 9.4 GiB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 10.10.8.125, 62134, None)
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 10.10.8.125, 62134, None)
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:11 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 10.10.8.125, 62134, None)
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:14 INFO SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir.
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:14 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:find-retired-people-scala/spark-warehouse'.
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:14 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 87.737958 ms
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:15 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 2.845959 ms
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:15 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 4.161 ms
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:15 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 5.464375 ms
[info] +-------+---+
[info] |   name|age|
[info] +-------+---+
[info] |Charlie| 80|
[info] +-------+---+
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:15 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.10.8.125:4040
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:15 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:15 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:15 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:15 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:15 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:15 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:15 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
[info] 23/04/24 13:19:15 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/22/ntjwd5dx691gvkktkspl0f_00000gq/T/spark-2a1a3b4a-efa4-4f43-9a0e-babff52aa946
[success] Total time: 9 s, completed Apr 24, 2023, 1:19:15 PM
```

I think I will stay with original harmless error in UPDATE 1 with no `fork := true`, because I do want to use Java 17.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your original question. Please edit your original question.

Comment: @ahinkle thanks! I edited the question, hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue until I have marked all spark related dependencies as `Provided` and redefined the `run` task as follows

```
val scala2Version = "2.12.18"

lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "hello-scala",
    version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
    scalaVersion := scala2Version,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.4.0" % Provided,
      "io.delta" %% "delta-core" % "2.4.0" % Provided,
      "org.scalameta" %% "munit" % "0.7.29" % Test
    )
  )

// include the 'provided' Spark dependency on the classpath for  sbt run
Compile / run := Defaults
  .runTask(
    Compile / fullClasspath,
    Compile / run / mainClass,
    Compile / run / runner
  )
  .evaluated
```

Try these changes in your `.sbt` file and let me know if it fixes the problem. This setup

- should not include any `spark` dependencies in the uber jar when you want to build and submit to an existing spark
- but will add all `Provided` dependencies to the classpath when you run it with `sbt run`

I found the idea here https://xebia.com/blog/using-scala-3-with-spark/